# Как сделать конструктор копирования в стеке?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Array{
    int size = 0;
    int *a;
    int top;
public:
    Array() = default;

    Array(int n) :size(n)
    {
        a = new int[size];
        top = 0;
    }    

    Array(const Array &ob) :size(ob.size)
    {           
        a = new int[ob.size];
        top = ob.top;


        for (int i = 0; i < ob.size; ++i)
            a[top] = ob.a[top];
    }

    ~Array()
    {
        delete[] a;
    }

    //GetSize - получение размера массива
    //(количество элементов, под которые выделена память) 
    int GetSize()
    {
        return size;
    }

    //IsEmpty - массив пуст? 
    void IsEmpty()
    {
        if (top == 0)
            cout << endl << "Array empty" << endl;
        else
            cout << endl << "Array doesn't empty" << endl;
    }

    //FreeExtra - удалить "лишнюю" память (выше последнего допустимого индекса) 
    void FreeExtra()
    {
        assert(top >0);
        for (int i = 0; top < size; ++i)
            a = new int[size--];

    }

    //RemoveAll - удалить все 
    void RemoveAll()
    {
        assert(top > 0);
        while (top != NULL)
            a[--top];
    }
    /*
    int getTop()
    {
    return top;
    }       
    */
    void push(int i)
    {
        assert(top < size);
        a[top++] = i;

    }

    void show()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < top; ++i)
            cout << a[i] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Array a(10);
    a.push(5);
    a.push(0);
    a.show();

    Array b = a;
    b.show();       

    return 0;
}
```

Как сделать чтоб top принимал номер текущего значения? Он у меня мусор выводит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструктор копирования следует определить следующим образом

```
Array( const Array &ob ) : size( ob.size ), top( obj.top ), a( nullptr ) 
{
    if ( size )
    {
        a = new int[size]();
        for ( int i = 0; i < top; i++ ) a[i] = obj.a[i];
    }
}
```

Желательно, чтобы член данных `size` имел тип `size_t`. Иначе вам придется проверять, не является ли `size` отрицательным числом.

Но у вас в определении класса есть и другие проблемы. Например, Конструктор с параметром должен проверять, является ли `size` больше нуля. Конструктор по умолчанию должен инициализировать все члены данных класса, в частности указатель `a`. Иначе программа может завершиться аварийно при вызове деструктора.
Необходимо также определить оператор присваивания.

Можно также определить конструктор перемещения и оператор перемещения.

Функции `GetSize`, `show` и `IsEmpty` следует сделать константными. Также вы должны определиться со стилем именования методов класса.

Функция `IsEmpty` вообще не имеет большого смысла. Я бы определил ее следующим образом

```
bool IsEmpty() const
{
    return top == 0;
}
```

Функция `FreeExtra` ошибочна. Ее следует определить следующим образом

```
void FreeExtra()
{
    assert( top > 0 );

    size = top;

    int *tmp = new int[top];

    for ( int i = 0; i < top; i++ ) tmp[i] = a[i];

    delete []a;

    a = tmp;
}
```

Функция `RemoveAll` может быть определена как

```
void RemoveAll()
{
    top = 0;
}
```

Comment: a = new int[size](); круглые скобки обезательно должы быть?

Comment: @Ilya Tikhonov Нет, конечно. Вы можете их удалить. Если они присутствуют, то они инициализируют нулем всю выделенную память под массив. Но у вас в этом необходимости нет.